# Error After Installing OpenCV 3.1 in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: opencv, ubuntu

After Installing OpenCV-3.1 in ubuntu and running sample program I got following error:

> /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lippicv collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status

Comment: How you installed opencv? However, I would recommend http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/06/22/install-opencv-3-0-and-python-2-7-on-ubuntu/

Comment: `ld` is the name of the linker program, It is looking for a C library called `ippicv` which it can't find on your system.  I would try `sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev`  or something like that.  Type `apt-cache search opencv` for a list of options.